# What are useful differences (if any) between [algorithms], [numerics], and [computational-statistics] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have just found myself adding these three tags ([numerics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerics), [algorithms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms), and [computational-statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-statistics)) to the following question (noticing an offered bounty): [What algorithm is used in linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1829) -- and it made me wonder if there are any worthy differences between these tags.

Below I copy-paste the current wiki excerpts (and numbers of questions). Notice that all three wiki excerpts mention **algorithms**, which seems to me the main topic of all these tags. Should we perhaps make them all synonyms? If not, what are the usage guidelines?

**Worse,** browsing the highest voted [computational-statistics] questions, I am wondering if we need this tag at all. It seems that it is used either when [algorithms] can be used as well, or when [software] would fit more, or, most disturbingly, instead of [statistics] tag (which is deprecated on CV) i.e. only adding noise. I am thinking that we should perhaps get rid of this tag altogether.

So it seems I have two questions:

1. Should we merge [numerics] into [algorithms]?
2. What should we do about [computational-statistics]?

---

- [algorithms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) (480) (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

  > An algorithm is a a set of one or more computations that will produce a calculated result. All statistics methods are algorithms. Algorithms can be simple, such as calculating a percentage, or can be very complex and require a computer for fast and accurate results.
- [computational-statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-statistics) (336)

  > Refers to the interface of statistics and computing; the use of algorithms and software for statistical purposes.
- [numerics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerics) (47)

  > Also known as Numerical Analysis, Numerics aims to provide methods and algorithms for numerical computations.

Comment: By now I think that [algorithms] and [numerics] are meaningfully different (we should edit the excerpts though), and [computational-statistics] is a rather useless tag that could in principle be burninated but most likely will stick around forever because we've never ever been able to burninate any tags here anyway.